# How to write data to database to a remote from another remote in another newtork thru SSH tunnel in bash script?

Tags: database, bash, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have three remote, PC_A have the python code while PC_B are on different network have the database and PC_C also have the database which have the same network with PC_A

I was able to load the data from PC_A to PC_C in script like the following:
IN PC_A,

```
#!/bin/sh
# echo "i am in bin testing"
/home/user/env/bin/python3.8 /home/user/load_to_db.py -e IP_OF_PC_C
```

And to load the data to PC_B , i open a SSH tunnel among PC_A and PC_B,
i was able to load the data to PC_B if i do the following:

```
ssh -L 9200:127.0.0.1:9200 -L 5601:127.0.0.1:5601 user@IP_PC_B -p 30020
```

which 30020 is the SSH portt, 5601/9200 are the ElasticSearch and Kibana port
and then run (in PC_A) the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# echo "i am in bin testing"
/home/user/env/bin/python3.8 /home/user/load_to_db.py -e localhost
```

I fail if i write the following in the

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh user@PC_B -p 30020
/home/user/env/bin/python3.8 /home/user/load_to_db.py -e PC_B
```

I was wondering how i write the above to script to transfer the data to PC_B with SSH
Thanks

Comment: Is `IP_OF_PC_C` wrong in your first example? The line above says that you transfer to B.

Comment: Is the last example wrong in that way, that it execution of python should be an argument to ssh? In general it does not make any sense to start an interactive ssh session in a script.

Comment: @ceving, yes thanks for point out. For second question , i dont understand , since my goal was to write some data to PC_B using crontab, i wonder how i do the SSH and the python script in one script

Answer (score 0):

i google a bit in "using local port forwarding in background" and "kill the ssh process" , i do a little test and below is what i need

```
ssh -N -f -L 9200:127.0.0.1:9200 user@IP_OF_PC_B -p 30020 
do python code in PC_A
kill $(ps aux | grep ssh | grep 9200 | awk '{print $2}')
```